# Scala `def loop(): Unit = loop`, why loop forever?

Tags: python, scala

In Scala

```
def loop():
   Unit = loop
```

When you call it:

```
loop()
```

It will loop forever. I can't understand why?

For example in Python:

```
def loop():
    return loop
```

When you call it:

```
loop()
```

It returns

```
<function loop at 0x7f276e680668>
```

In Scala, is everything an expression which automatically adds `()`?

```
println(println())
```

It returns a blank line:

```
()
```

Comment: Been awhile since I've coded Scala, but yes, I believe you can omit the parentheses if the function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Commenting to confirm @Carcigenicate's belief.

Comment: It's an [Arity-0](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-0), so yes, you can omit the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

From the Scala [style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html):

"Scala allows the omission of parentheses on methods of arity-0 (no arguments):

```
reply() 

// is the same as

reply
```

However, this syntax should only be used when the method in question has no side-effects (purely-functional). In other words, it would be acceptable to omit parentheses when calling queue.size, but not when calling println(). This convention mirrors the method declaration convention given above.

Religiously observing this convention will dramatically improve code readability and will make it much easier to understand at a glance the most basic operation of any given method. Resist the urge to omit parentheses simply to save two characters!"

Comment: val test = () => {println("asdf")} ;  
test;
test();
why this is different?

Comment: @jin "Scala allows the omission of parentheses on **methods** of arity-0". That's not a method.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the parentheses and it calls the function without arguments.  It's not like Python.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, methods that take no parameters can be invoked with or without the parentheses, but only if it is defined with parentheses.

```
def one() = 1
def two = 2

one    // 1
one()  // 1
two    // 2
two()  // error: Int does not take parameters
```

The `()` output from `println(println())` is a bit different.  A `println()` statement returns `Unit` which is a type that has only one possible value, which is expressed as `()`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, of course it is, just as any other `def`. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, `two` is the method here, not `2` :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get a reference to non-anonymous functions in Scala as well. For example, here we have two functions:

```
def callFunc(f: Unit => Unit): Unit = f()
def printUnit(x: Unit): Unit = println(x)
```

The first function accepts a reference to another function which returns `Unit`, calls that function and returns the resulting `Unit`, while the second function takes a value of type `Unit`, prints it, and returns `Unit`.

For example, the following compiles:

```
callFunc(printUnit)
```

as does this:

```
printUnit(callFunc(printUnit))
```

But not this:

```
callFunc(printUnit())
```

Why? Because `callFunc` takes a reference to a function with signature `Unit => Unit`, which `printUnit` satisfies, and so the compiler figures out that we must want the `<function1>` object. It then returns a value of typ `Unit`, which `printUnit` accepts and prints.

However, if we append the parens after `printUnit`, we explicitly make a call to it, returning `Unit`. So the third example doesn't compile, because `callFunc` only takes a reference to a function, it does not accept a simple value of type `Unit`.

If you want to explitly reference a function where the compiler can't otherwise derive that intent, you can use [currying](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/30/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-11-currying-and-partially-applied-functions.html):

```
val f = loop _
```

However, if you're explicit about your types, the compiler can figure that out itself:

```
val f: () => Unit = loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers. Apart from the parentheses, Scala can behave similar way to Python. Compare the two examples below:

```
//scala
def loop(): () => Unit = {
  println("function executed")
  loop _
}
scala> loop
function executed
res0: () => Unit = <function0>
scala> loop _
res1: () => () => Unit = <function0>

#python
def loop():
    print("function executed")
    return loop
>>> loop()
function executed
<function loop at 0x1090f07d0>
>>> loop
<function loop at 0x1090f07d0>
```

The difference is that in Python you can execute the function by calling `loop()`, reference the function calling `loop`, in Scala you can execute the function calling `loop()` or `loop` and reference the function calling `loop _`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to all the other answers: the most fun and correct way to type `loop` in scala is this.

```
def loop(): T forSome {type T <: () => T} = {
  println("function executed")
  loop _
}

loop()()()()()()
```